# Display first 2 flex items centered to each other and top aligned

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I am trying to center align the first 2 blocks to each other (the blocks with a purple border) and have all 3 boxes top aligned. I have achieved this using `display: inline-flex`, but would it be possible to have the same results using just `display: flex`?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6L28yd9p/)

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blocks {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.blocks-left {
  align-items: center;
  width: 66%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.blocks-right {
  width: 33%;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
}

#block-1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

#block-2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

#block-3 {
  background: green;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blocks blocks-left">
    <div id="block-1" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block-2" class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocks blocks-right">
   <div id="block-3" class="block"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change `blocks` to *block-level* `display: flex`, you can get the same result if you make your `container` a *flexbox* and add `align-self: flex-start` to the `blocks-left` element - see demo below:

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex; /* added */
}

.blocks {
  display: flex; /* now flex instead of inline-flex */
}

.blocks-left {
  align-items: center;
  align-self: flex-start; /* added */
  width: 66%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.blocks-right {
  width: 33%;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
}

#block-1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

#block-2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

#block-3 {
  background: green;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blocks blocks-left">
    <div id="block-1" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block-2" class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocks blocks-right">
   <div id="block-3" class="block"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display: flex` to the main container along with `align-items: flex-start` might work. Is this what you need?

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.blocks {
  display: flex;
}

.blocks-left {
  align-items: center;
  width: 66%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.blocks-right {
  width: 33%;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
}

#block-1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

#block-2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

#block-3 {
  background: green;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blocks blocks-left">
    <div id="block-1" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block-2" class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocks blocks-right">
    <div id="block-3" class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```